# Can microservices be used to display a regular page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microservices

I have been researching microservices and noticed that each author discourages use of monolithic architecture when its large. They say in enterprise environments microservices are highly advisable. My question is what about displaying normal data such as this stackoverflow question that you're reading. How would this page load in a microservice environment? The request would need to be queued then another microservice would need to fetch and return the data. When the request is queued the request context is lost - the page will return when the data is queued. How will the system display the data to the page when the request has already returned to the browser?

The only way I can see this working is the browser would need to poll a web api for the new data.

Comment: Look at UI composition frameworks and SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

Very broad topic for just one question and answer, but I'll do my best with this scenario.

The concept of microservices is to have independent pieces of the whole where at any given time any of the microservices could go down and other areas wouldn't be affected.  So, if you wanted Stack Overflow (SO) to have the HTML of this question running in a microservice, one way would be to have a QuestionService responsible for taking new questions. This service could process anything it needs to do with the actual question and then post a pub-sub type message that a new question was added. The HtmlService would pick up this message and do all the HTML rending it needed and might need to ask other services for additional data before it can finish its job. It may need to ask a UserService for additional data about the posting user. Once the HtmlService has all the info it needs it could save the HTML into it's own database for persistence.

Now some other user requests from SO to get new questions. The request is routed to the HtmlService and the already generated HTML is served.

Now all questions can still be seen and if the QuestionService or the UserService goes down, all the HTML can still be served. You couldn't add new questions or register new users, but the site as a knowledge base would still work.

I hope this crude example answers your question. Feel free to comment and I'll do my best to go into more detail.

Comment: Once the browser loads the querstion the backend will queue the request. Then the browser will say something like "we are finding your question". because the request returned to the browser. How would the browser get populated with the question data? In a monolithic app the request does not return until ALL the data is fetched.

Comment: The HtmlService is now just serving static HTML files like so.com/questions.html which could list all questions. Or so.com/1234.html for an individual question. All the work of generating the HTML is done behind the scenes when the HtmlService gets notified of new questions. This is why you may see just a slight delay from someone posting a new question to it being visible on so.com. Backend microservices are doing the heavy lifting of gathering all the data and generating HTML files to be served statically. There is no queue or "finding your question" returned, just the question HTML.

Comment: As you can see, microservices is such a broad topic with many right and wrong ways of doing it. Much like any other project, individual needs will determine the use case. There will be no "right" way to do it, but there are best practices and many examples. The tough thing is finding real world examples because many online are so high level it's hard to apply. It's a really abstract concept and this is where a Systems Architect could come into play.